# How to programmatically get FCM sent, opened, and converted reports?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Cloud Messaging has a UI to see the sent, opened, and converted stats for a single message sent. Additionally, it has a downloadable CSV of counts for number of messages sent, displayed and opened for a given day.

Is there a programmatic API to get all of these stats so they can be integrated into a larger analytics system? Or is the UI and the CSV the only source for this data?

Comment: this is not a duplicate question. This question is about accessing FCM Analytics data programmatically, the question you have linked to this one is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API to get the reports data (sent, opened, converted) from FCM. However, there's been a recent improvement in the Firebase Notifications console where stats (sent count only for now) for messages sent using the FCM API is included in the Firebase Notification console stats. From my answer in the duplicate post:

> As of August 2018, stats for messages sent using the FCM API are now visible from the console. From the *Cloud Messaging* section, click on the *Reports* tab. From there, you will be able to filter by message type (`notification`, `data`, and all)
>
> [image]
>
> It would seem that the *Impressions* and *Opens* are still only available for messages sent using the console. But *Sends* for sure now counts the messages sent using the FCM API.
>
> Reference: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/in-app-messaging-crashlytics.html